# What is this plastic insert called? (Secures a wood screw to a cabinet door.)

Tags: cabinets, hinges

The European hinges on my kitchen cabinet doors are held in place with wood screws that anchor into plastic inserts - see the picture below.  The one on the right is cracked.  I would like to replace it but I do not know what it is called.  What are these little plastic insert/anchors called?  Thanks.

(The yellow/translucent stuff stuck on the cabinet door near the anchor on the right seems to be glue that someone else tried to use to repair the split anchor.  The anchors themselves fit in the holes, like the one on the left.)

[image]

Comment: Just because the manufacturer used those plastic dowels doesn't mean you have to fix it with that.  For instance, if you can remove all the glue and plastic (maybe drill it out) a hardwood dowel glued into place could work just as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are called [plastic dowels](http://www.wwhardware.com/blum-plastic-dowels-and-screws-blum-dowel-and-screws)

[image: plastic dowels]

There are different sizes for different brands of hinges. Also note that they take special screws.

Search *hinge plastic dowels* and add the brand of hinge, if you know it.

```
 Images and links are for illustration only, not an endorsement of goods or sources.
```

Answer (score 2):

The common industry term is "[wall anchor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BO6NY2)" and are designed in wide range of shapes and sizes. They are used to anchor and secure objects and material to surfaces that would otherwise not have the strength or 'gripping power' to retain a screw or fastener.

The adjustable hinge in your photo possibly needed an anchor due to the screw becoming loose. The hole was enlarged to accept the appropriate sized anchor so that the hinge could be re-secured.

Comment: Actually European style hinges can be mounted with regular screws directly into the door or into specialized plastic dowel inserts described in my answer. This is a routine original mount, not a fix for a bad initial hob. Custom cabinet door companies offer you the choice of plain screw or dowel pre-drilling.

Comment: @bib- I guess the screws are less likely to tear-out with the plastic anchors? I usually mount them as you say, with regular course threaded screws.

Comment: The stock screws for Euro hinges are flat bottommed, lacking points, but have conventional pitch.